# Is there a way to export my existing connections from MySQL Workbench to Sequel PRO

Tags: mysql-workbench, sequelpro

Is there a way to export my existing connections from MySQL Workbench to Sequel PRO

I have been  browsing through all options I could and I cant find an option that would let me export all my connections from workbench

I have a lot of connections in the workbench and I am planning on using sequel pro now.

Comment: Here is a bug related to "Backup file creation error" when attempting the current accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31862137/470749 https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102501

Comment: On ubuntu (installed via snap): ~/snap/mysql-workbench-community/9/.mysql/workbench/connections.xml

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Unfortunately due to the fact that Sequel Pro does not have option to import connections at all, you will be unable to import the connections.

---

There are two ways in order to export your connections from MySQL Workbench into a file:

1. Follow the procedure to export the connections from the menu:

   `Open and Select MySQL Workbench > In the Menu bar select Tools > Configuration > Backup Connections`
2. Find the CONNECTIONS.XML file located at

   `Users/Username/Library/Application Support/MySQL/Workbench/connections.xml`

---

About Sequel Pro...

1. The connections strings are stored in the following preference file:

   `~/Library/Preferences/com.sequelpro.SequelPro.plist`
2. The passwords are stored in the Mac OSX Keychain, which is stored here:

   `~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain`

Comment: Ah that's a bummer. I dont want to keep setting up connections in the sequel pro.. I will stick to workbench for now. And thanks for the answer

Comment: You are welcome. It will be greatly appreciated if you mark it as an answer at least.

Comment: `Sequel Pro does not have option to import connections at all` not true check the [JAstuccio's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37145386/316700)

Comment: That is a new feature. It was not available back in 2015.

Comment: For number 2. Run the 'Keychain Access' Application in OSX, search for SequelPro and all your connections are listed. Right click 'export password' and job done.

Comment: Windows 10 path for connections.xml will be Users\User\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench

Comment: Error: Backup file creation error; Could not create the backup file. Please check path and permissions and try again. (MySQL Workbench 8.0.26 on Windows 10)

Answer (score 40):

You can import a plist file using Sequel Pro. Click the gear icon in the bottom left.

credit to [james-chevalier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359957/james-chevalier) for showing me how to do this.

[image: sequel pro import screenshot]

Comment: Great answer - nice that you can import/export from that menu - you can also select multiple. I had a time machine backup so the keychain/password thing was there, but for whatever reason the favorites didn't come across. +1

Comment: hi - this is what i hoped for, but perhaps i am missing something obvious. i copied over the plist via airdrop - when i try to import via the 'import' i get 'error reading import file'. any thoughts?

Comment: syntax error in your plist file maybe? @petednz-fuzion

Comment: If you copy the file, you will get an error. Select all your connections, click on the Settings icon and click Export selected. Then you will be able to import that file.

Answer (score 14):

1. Open `Keychain Access` using Alfred.
2. Find (top right of GUI): `sequel`
3. Double-click the result you're looking for... It should be something like `root@localhost/`
4. Checkbox `Show Password`
5. Type in your Mac password
6. Enjoy