# Export MySQL Workbench connection to command line

Tags: mysql, ssl, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I'm connected to an Amazon RDS instance through MySQL workbench. The connection uses both username/password and ssl. I'd like to connect to the same instance using the command line. I tried ...

`mysql -h $RDS_HOSTNAME -P $RDS_PORT -u $RDS_USERNAME -p --ssl-ca=$SSL_CA_PATH`

and entered my password, but I got the following error ...

`ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XXX' (60)`

Clearly MySQL workbench is doing some additional step that I'm missing.

I read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861576/is-there-a-way-to-export-my-existing-connections-from-mysql-workbench-to-sequel) about exporting connections to an `.xml`, and was able to generate that, but I'm not sure how to transcribe that output into the command line beyond what I've already tried.

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I just added the error message