# How to export MySQL Workbench connections and import them into Sequel Ace?

Tags: mysql-workbench

Is there a way to export all saved connections(local and ssh) in MySQL Workbench and import them into Sequel Ace?
It would be preferable to have an option that exports them all together, but exporting them individually could be an acceptable workaround.

Exporting via .xml is not being imported by Sequel Ace, as it has .plist backup files.

[image: SequelAce]

---

- [Related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861576/is-there-a-way-to-export-my-existing-connections-from-mysql-workbench-to-sequel)